# Does each process has its own portion of utopia in the memory?

Tags: memory, assembly, stack-overflow, buffer-overflow

By doing some `cat /proc/*some PID*/maps` on multiple processes on a machine, I notice they all have the same starting point in regards to memory address, being `0x8048000`. Does this mean that every process has "it's own memory space, including stack, heap etc." at runtime?

And if so, how can attackers for instance distinguish between memory address of one process to another?

So if a machine has 2GB of RAM, and a few processes are running simultaneously - How can we know what memory address we are targeting? Or am I getting this all wrong, and the attack starts by looking at the process itself and then advancing from there?

Pardon the *beginner's* question, I am just getting into Assembly and am reading 5 tutorials simultaneously and having a bit of a hard-time grasping it all to a level of understanding.

Please note this question was put here and not in IT Security since I do refer to the Assembly side of things.

Answer (score 5):

Each process has its own "virtual memory", where it stores its own stack, heap, instructions, etc. Each process can use the entire 32/64-bit address space independently of any other process. The kernel manages the mapping between each processes virtual memory and the machine's physical RAM. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) covers this in more detail.

Most attacks target memory in one particular process. Attackers use addresses from the address space of the process they are targeting. As you observed, many executables load at standard virtual addresses, making it easier for attackers to predict the memory layout of a process.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If so, how does ASLR helps me as means of defense? How will it deny me the possibility of observing the address space of the stack?

Comment: @Franko ASLR unties things from fixed addresses and makes successful attacks that depend on things being at specific locations less probable. E.g. if there are now 256 possible locations for everything, ideally only 1 attack out of 256 may still succeed.